# How to assign unique Employee on weekends in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list of 7 employees. I am iterating a loop of dates for the current month and want to assign two employees on each date, but on weekends they should not repeat until all employees are being assigned. For Example: I am having seven employees:

```
John         
Sophia       
Olivia
Davis          
Clark          
Paul         
Thomas
```

Now my date loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
 {
       DateTime newDate = new DateTime();
        newDate = dates[i];
      /*if(newdate == "Saturday")
        var EmpName1 = emplist[i];
        var EmpName2 = emplist[i];*/
 }
```

In the above loop I want to assign two employees each on Saturday and Sunday until all other have not been assigned previously. Something like this:

```
4th March: John and Sophia
5th March: Olivia and Davis
11th March: Clark and Paul
12th March: Thomas and John
```

and so on.... John will not be assigned till all of them are assigned. After that the list will start again. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is your desired result, a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>`?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: if(newDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || newDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)

Comment: So these employess must work at weekend? Then they should not week also in the week, otherwise they work more than others.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This condition is only for weekends for not repeating the employees but on weekdays they can be repeated any number of times.

Comment: @munmunpoddar: so it's possible that someone is assigned at friday and also at saturday?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes. Only condition for unique assignment is for weekends only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate index for the person to chose every time you need to chose one.
After selecting, change the index with:

```
index = (index + 1) % employees.Length // Number fo employees
```

The % (means modulo) makes sure the counter starts at 0 again when employees.Length is reached.

So something like:

```
var empIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
{
   DateTime newDate = new DateTime();
    newDate = dates[i];
    if(newdate == "Saturday") // and Sunday, use or: || (newData == "Sunday"))
    {
       var EmpName1 = emplist[empIndex];
       empIndex = (empIndex + 1) % empList.Length;
       var EmpName2 = emplist[empIndex];
       empIndex = (empIndex + 1) % empList.Length;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that this boils down to ordering the employees by DateOfLastWeekendOnCall?

```
var e = Employees.OrderBy(i=>i.DateOfLastWeekendOnCall).First();
e.DateOfLastWeekendOnCall = weekendThatNeedsAssigning;
```

Explaination:

"dont assign the employee until all other employees have also been assigned"

is equivalent to

"assign the employee whose maximum date assigned to is the lowest of all employees (or who has never been assigned)"

So if you keep track of the last Saturday each employee was assigned to, its trivial to see which employee you should assign to the next date.

You can put in some special logic to handle the null case, or just put in MinDate as a default value

Comment: Can you please explain it more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue:

```
var weekendWarriors = new Queue<string>();
CheckRefreshQueue<string>(weekendWarriors, employees);

for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
{
    DateTime newDate = new DateTime();
    newDate = dates[i];

    if (newDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || newDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {   
        string emp1;
        string emp2;
        CheckRefreshQueue<string>(weekendWarriors, employees);
        emp1 = weekendWarriors.Dequeue();
        CheckRefreshQueue<string>(weekendWarriors, employees);
        emp2 = weekendWarriors.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Here's `CheckRefreshQueue`:

```
private static void CheckRefreshQueue<T>(Queue<T> toRefresh, IEnumerable<T> fromCollection)
{
    if (toRefresh.Count == 0) foreach (T item in fromCollection) toRefresh.Enqueue(item);
}
```